# Setting cell value loses border style

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro that enters a value into a cell based on the value of another cell. Everything works, except that after the macro runs the cell in which the value was entered no longer has a border. Any idea how to enter just the value and not lose the border style for the cell? Below is the statement:

```
Sub copy()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As 
    Worksheet, acode1 As Long, acode2 As Long
    k = 2

    Set acode1 = "LECO"
    Set acode2 = "OM"
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S1700038com")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UPLOAD")

    ws2.Range("A2:E113").Clear

    For i = 5 To 65

    If Len(ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value) = 7 Then      'Check if SIDN length
        If Not IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(i, 4)) Then        'Check if there is an EC result
            ws1.Cells(i, 3).copy ws2.Cells(k, 1)        'Copy SIDN
            ws2.Cells(k, 2).Value = "EC"            'Enter ACODE
            ws1.Cells(i, 4).copy ws2.Cells(k, 3)            'Copy Result
            ws1.Cells(2, 8).copy ws2.Cells(k, 4)        'Copy ASTD
            ws1.Cells(3, 8).copy ws2.Cells(k, 5)                'Copy AANALYST

            k = k + 1                           'increment ws2 row counter

            If Not IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(i, 5)) Then
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).copy ws2.Cells(k, 1)      'Copy SIDN
                ws2.Cells(k, 2).Value = "PH"            'Enter ACODE
                ws1.Cells(i, 5).copy ws2.Cells(k, 3)            'Copy Result
                ws1.Cells(2, 8).copy ws2.Cells(k, 4)        'Copy ASTD
                ws1.Cells(3, 8).copy ws2.Cells(k, 5)                'Copy AANALYST
                k = k + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What's the rest of your code?

Comment: There must be something else doing the removal.  That line will not do that.

Comment: @BigBen Updated with the rest of the code. The fields that I am copying from do have the border around the cell.

Comment: You clear the formatting here: `ws2.Range("A2:E113").Clear`. And you never copy anything to `ws2.Cells(k, 2)`... so it has no border.

Comment: use [`.ClearContents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents) not [`.Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clear)

Comment: @ScottCraner ahhhhhhhhh. rookie mistake. thanks Scott.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to use the copy method of the range but rather assign values:

```
ws2.Cells(i,j).Value = ws1.Cells(k,n).Value
```

This completely ignores cell formatting

Comment: Better yet use relative positioning with `ws2.Range("C5").Cells(i,j).Value = ws1.Range("D5").Cells(k,n).Value`